# Cannot read property 'name' of undefined angular 4

Tags: angular, typescript

I am trying to print a value in the template of component.

But I am getting the above error
`Cannot read property 'name' of undefined`

I have removed the extra contents from code for this question. I want to access the first row of the details.

Components file

```
import {
  Component
} from '@angular/core';
import {
  Person
} from './person';
import {
  getPersonDetailsService
} from './person.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `
      {{data[0].name}}
      `
})
export class AppComponent {
  data: Person[] = [];
  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.getPersonDetailsService.getData()
      .then(data => this.data = data.slice(1, 5));
  }

}
```

Answer (score 22, accepted):

I think you should first check if data is defined when you print it in browser.

```
{{data[0]?.name}}
```

As your data is not defined initially, you cannot access the name property of it.

[Documentation](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/template-syntax.html#!#ref-vars)

> The Angular safe navigation operator (?.) is a fluent and convenient
>   way to guard against null and undefined values in property paths. Here
>   it is, protecting against a view render failure if the currentHero is
>   null.

You can also check if the variable is null or not by using `&&` condition

`{{data[0] && data[0].name}}`

Comment: Thankyou, the console error was resolved. Can you explain more why it was happening and how it was resolved?

Comment: @Netdeamon I have edited the answer. You can read the documentation.

Answer (score 0):

From your error message, it seems like `data` is undefined (or is empty) - and the error is happening on the line that says

```
{{data[0].name}}
```

Maybe put in a `console.log(data)` before then to verify what is going on

Answer (score 0):

Try put this into constructor instead of ngOnInit:

```
getPersonDetailsService.getData() ...
```

Also, you need to make some check inside template in case that 'data' does not have length > 0 `{{data[0]?.name}}`

Answer (score 0):

The value for the "data" is getting updated after response is resolved from your getData() service. I am assuming you are hitting a service and getting the data. Nevertheless, the promise would be resolved once the service returns the response. The View meanwhile tries to render the template and as it evaluates the expression data[0], its doesn't find any element at 0 as the data has not still arrived from the service. Hence you get the error as the element at 0th index is undefined.

You should be using an observable here.